# OWIN Authentication works fine locally but not on dev environment

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, owin

I am facing some weird issue. 
I have a login form in popup. When form is submitted AJAX request is sent to server,with encrypted login and password and anti-forgery token as parameters. Controller method is called, this method checks user input and can return:

a)  if user input is incorrect then HTML for partial view (login form) with validation errors, which is injected instead of existing login form

b) if user input is correct, then page is refreshed and re-displayed for authenticated user.
I am using OWIN to authenticate users.

Javascript - AJAX call

```
"use strict";(function ($, undefined) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('submit', 'div.modal-dialog form', function () {
        let $form = $(this),
            //token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val(),
            logindata = $form.serialize(),
            $formParent = $form.parent();
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',//form.attr('method'),
            data: {
                mdata: b64Encode(logindata),
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.resultsuccess) {
                    location.reload(true);
                }
                let $resultHtml = $('<div/>').html(result).contents();
                let mbody = $resultHtml.find('div.modal-body');
                if (mbody.length) {
                    $formParent.children().remove();
                    $formParent.html($resultHtml.find('div.modal-body').children());
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });



function GetAntiForgeryToken() {
    let tokenField = $("input[type='hidden'][name$='RequestVerificationToken']");
    if (tokenField.length == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return {
            name: tokenField[0].name,
            value: tokenField[0].value
        };
    }
}

$.ajaxPrefilter(
    function (options, localOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (options.type !== "GET") {
            let token = GetAntiForgeryToken();
            if (token !== null) {
                if (options.data.indexOf("X-Requested-With") === -1) {
                    options.data = "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest" + ((options.data === "") ? "" : "&" + options.data);
                }
                options.data = options.data + "&" + token.name + '=' + token.value;
            }
        }
    }
 );})(jQuery);
```

Controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private CustomUserManager cman;

    public AccountController()
    {
        cman = new CustomUserManager();
    }
    public AccountController(CustomUserManager customUserManager)
    {
        cman = customUserManager;
    }
    //[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public PartialViewResult LoginView()
    {
        LoginViewModel lm = new LoginViewModel();
        return PartialView("Login",lm);
    }



    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string mdata)
    {
        LoginViewModel model = LoginViewModel.FromFormData(mdata);
        ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(model);
        List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, results);
        if (isValid)
        {
            var user = await cman.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                //return JavaScript("location.reload(true);");
                return Json(new { resultsuccess = "1" });
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                return PartialView(model);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            results.ForEach(entry => ModelState.AddModelError("", entry.ErrorMessage));
            return PartialView(model);
         }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return Redirect("~/");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && cman != null)
        {
            cman.Dispose();
            cman = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }

    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        //AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await cman.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }

    private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
    {
        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
        }
    }
}
```

OWIN startup file

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/")
            //,CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest
        });
        // app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


    }
```

All this stuff works great on my local machine. But on dev server this code works only if user login/password are wrong: partial view with validation summary is returned. If login/password are correct, page is not refreshed as I expect. If I refresh page manually user is still not loggged in.

When I try AJAX call in Chrome it fails with error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and has status 0, in Edge the error is: Network Error 0x2eff, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002eff. In Firefox no error, but still authentication is not working. However, it has status 200 OK, and response is: {"resultsuccess":"1"} (in Firefox).

I have tried to wrap

```
await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
```

in controller in try/catch, but no exception was thrown.

Have also tried to AJAX call to action from another controller - worked fine.
So I don't even have a clue where this weird problem can be: OWIN, XMLHTTPRequest or possibly some IIS/machine settings on DEV environment.

**UPDATE**

Have created test page with simple non-AJAX login form. Same story, user is authenticated locally on form submit but not on DEV server. So it looks like XMLHTTPRequest is not the problem.

**Update 2**
So it is the authentication cookie which is set on local machine but not on DEV for some reason.

Either the SignInAsync method call fails or cookies are not sent to browser by IIS or ASP.Net

Comment: So in Firefox, with a response of `{"resultsuccess":"1"}`, it does reload the page?

Comment: Nope. Page is not reloaded, I just can see response in Firebug.

Comment: Have just re-checked Firebug console, request is shown es error though status is 200, {"resultsuccess":"1"} is "responseText" property of "result" object in XHR error handler.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/PNI0E this is how it looks like in Firebug.

Comment: Can you double check if in your local server an auth cookie is being set, but this cookie is not set in your DEV server?

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET yes, auth cookie was set on local server (with name like "".AspNet....", don't remember exactly). Have just tried to login on DEV server, cookie is not created.

Comment: Have a look at these two issues and see if it fits your experience: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/197 http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=System.Web%20response%20cookie%20integration%20issues

Comment: @BrentSchmaltz unfortunately, suggested solutions didn't work for me. Thanks for posting links anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between my local machine and DEV server was IIS version: IIS 10 (Windows 10) at my local vs IIS 8.5 on DEV (Windows server 2012). Have tried to deploy the site at virtual machine with IIS 8.5 - OWIN authentication didn't work too. 
Have tried solution from 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877699/owin-and-asp-net-membership-in-iis-8-5-not-working), still couldn't get it work.

So, unfortunately, I had to remove OWIN from project and implement custom membership provider to make authentication work on DEV server.